# Created clock on Android is not updating

Tags: android, user-interface, time, clock

I´m trying to create a fullscreen clock. I managed to set text for hours, minutes and seconds. Well, but when I start the app, it shows the time but the UI is not updating... I dont know how to do it, I read this tutorial but i dont understand it... any one can explain me how to consantly update the UI?

```
 public class Clock1Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Timer timer;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

final TextView txtHour = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtHour);
final TextView txtMinutes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtMinute);
final TextView txtSeconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtSeconds);
final TextView txtMilliseconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtMilliseconds);

 final Integer hora = new Integer(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
 final Integer minutos = new Integer(Calendar.MINUTE);
 final Integer segundos = new Integer(Calendar.SECOND);
 final Long milisegundos = new Long (System.currentTimeMillis());
    timer = new Timer("DigitalClock");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Get the Current Time
    final Runnable updateTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
/** txtHour.setText(hora.toString());
 txtMinutes.setText(minutos.toString());
 txtSeconds.setText(segundos.toString()); */
 txtMilliseconds.setText(milisegundos.toString());
 Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), milisegundos.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast1.show();
        }
    };

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(updateTask);
        }
    }, 1, 1000);
```

}

}

Just tell me how to complete it to update UI,please...

Comment: If you want some one to explain... thenyou should show some part of your code also... to suggest improvements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this](http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/create-apps-to-show-digital-time-in_19.html) example for Create a Apps to Show Digital Time in Android .And in your case use

`runOnUiThread` for Upadting time on UI.as

```
CurrentActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //UPDATE TIME HERE
    }
});
```

and your code look like:

```
public class Clock1Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private Timer timer;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView txtHour = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtHour);
    final TextView txtMinutes = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtMinute);
    final TextView txtSeconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtSeconds);
    final TextView txtMilliseconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtMilliseconds);


        timer = new Timer("DigitalClock");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Get the Current Time
        final Runnable updateTask = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
     final Integer hora = new Integer(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
     final Integer minutos = new Integer(Calendar.MINUTE);
     final Integer segundos = new Integer(Calendar.SECOND);
     final Integer milisegundos = new Integer(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
     txtHour.setText(hora.toString());
     txtMinutes.setText(minutos.toString());
     txtSeconds.setText(segundos.toString());
     txtMilliseconds.setText(milisegundos.toString());
            }
        };

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(updateTask);
            }
        }, 1, 1000);
 }

}
```

Comment: by using this, you mean do this?     CurrentActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        txtHour.setText(hora.toString());
                  txtMinutes.setText(minutos.toString());
                  txtSeconds.setText(segundos.toString());
         txtMilliseconds.setText(milisegundos.toString());  
    }
});

Comment: see this example http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/create-apps-to-show-digital-time-in_19.html you need to use timer with 1000 delay

Comment: thanks a lot, but timer = new Timer("DigitalClock") and timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() give me an error: timer cannot be resolved

Comment: create an Timer timer instnce

Comment: ok, I tried that... installed into my Xperia Play, but time only updates when i rotate screen... any solution?

Comment: ok see my edit plz @user1354096 make a toast in Timer for checking timer is running or not

Comment: okay, not succeeded.. toast appear constantly, but time is the same ( first post edited)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which tutorial you're working on, so just in case, you'll probably want to use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).